# Getting HTML textarea controls to expand to width of container

Tags: html, layout, textarea, css

I want my textarea controls to follow standard block display layout behavior, so that they expand to the width of the containing parent. Simply setting `display:block;` won't do this- they default to some default with value. Setting `width:100%;` doesn't work because any padding in the controls means they spill over the container bounds.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div >test</div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <textarea >test</textarea>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    border:black solid 1px;
    margin:10px;
}
.container > div {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    background:red;
}
.container > textarea {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    background:red;
}
```

​
**RESULT:**

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/hKcjc/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the css3 property called box-sizing to solve this: http://jsfiddle.net/QK78b/

Add the following:

```
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

See [Box Sizing | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) for an explanation of this issue and how it relates to TextAreas

Comment: Add "box-shadow: none;"